# Apex test fails when it should pass

Tags: apex, unit-test

This assertion is in my Apex test:

```
System.assertEquals(newLead.Inflation__c, 4.224);
```

And it returns this failure:

```
System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: null, Actual: 4.224
```

Shouldn't this work just fine? Do I have it backwards?

In my class I have these lines:

```
for(Lead l: leads) {
    l.Inflation__c = 4.224;
}
```

But the middle line is highlighted red indicating that it's not covered by the test. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if that line is not covered you will never get inflation__c value, it will be always null. make sure you have leads for this for loop. post your test class code here.

Comment: As @Himanshu said, usually that means that your code is getting to the for loop (so it's being covered), but there's nothing in `leads` to loop though. So the middle line isn't executing anything because there's nothing to execute against, so that isn't being covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it backwards in the sense that `System.assertEquals` takes first the *expected value*, then the *actual value*. So you should type `System.assertEquals (4.224, newLead.Inflation__c)`.

This highlights the issue that the inflation field on the lead is null when it shouldn't. We need to see the rest of the code to know what's wrong, but you're probably not updating the lead objects after setting their inflation value.